# Loosing focus in CKEditor after using jQuery to paste a content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, focus

I'm using CKEditor to edit some comments on my Article page.
When i click on the "Edit" button, a modal shows up with a CKEditor field. I use some jQuery to "copy-paste" the content of the initial comment so that the user can now edit it.
The problem is here, the content is paste in the CKEditor but the focus is lost and i can't find a way to change the text.
This is my twig view:

```
{% if comment.user == app.user %}
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
        <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-lg-end">
            <div class="col-10 col-lg-4">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button id="editBtn-{{ comment.id }}" data-id="{{ comment.id }}" type="button" class="editBtn btn btn-warning w-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCenter">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Éditer
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('.editBtn').click(function() {  
    let commentId = "#comment-" + $(this).data("id");
    let editComment = $(commentId).html();
    $('#cke_2_contents ').html(editComment);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this:

```
$('#cke_2_contents').attr("contenteditable", true);
```

Adding this attribute did the job !